# Can you have multiple evaluations in your WHEN clause?

Tags: haskell

Can you have multiple evaluations in your WHEN clause?

For example is there a way to do something like this:

```
when (x == "Open" and y == "Ready") $ do...
```

I can get a single condition to work, but what if I need both to be true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like

```
when (x == "Open" && y == "Ready") $ do
   ...
```

`&&` is just a normal infix operator defined as

```
True  && a = a
False && _ = False
```

Notice that with laziness this has exactly the same short circuiting properties we get in other languages!

---

On a totally separate note, instead of using strings to represent different states the Haskell-ish way would be to define your own type

```
data StateOfFoo = Ready
                | Open
                | Closed
                | ...
                deriving(Eq)
```

and then use `x == Open && y == Ready` for example. This way you make it clear in the types what you expect `x` and `y` to be.

Comment: @JSchwartz No worries I've been there :)